# How can I quickly determine what files on a windows system have changed?

Tags: windows

I need a tool, utility, or script that will quickly scan all of the files on a windows system (including ones that are locked down for editing) and tell me which have been modified. It needs to output the data in a way that I can send the data to scripts to run further processing on those files.

I tried using

```
dir -recurse | %{ $_.FullName} | %{ Get-FileHash $_}}
```

in windows power shell, but that takes an hour to run, and doesn't read files that are being used by another process.

I feel like there must be a right way to do this, but I don't know what it is and I haven't found anything by searching.

I'm currently working on windows 10, but a solution that runs on vista+ would be ideal.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are  you asking for software? But asking for software recommendation is off-topic here.

Comment: Software is one possible solution, but not the only one. Is there a better place to ask?

Comment: Ask here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. I've this old one http://www.moo0.com/software/FileMonitor/

Comment: It seems a little unclear what your goals are (assuming, say, a script was a possibility). For instance, is this continuous real-time monitoring? Why is an hour too long (especially with a large hard drive)? It feels like you have a clearer idea of "the right way" than we may have.

Comment: Good Questions Anaksunaman. I want to run a script every night on every computer on a network to identify new executables so that they can be checked by other software. I'm not 100% sure that an hour is too long, but it feels a little on the long side. Sorry I can't pin it down more than it just "Feels" too long.

Comment: Do you need to check for changes in ALL files, or just the contents of a specific directory or directories.

Comment: All files. Or rather all executables. I only care about executables.

Comment: (1) How long does it take to backup your entire system?  If you want to hash every file, you should expect that to take about as long (subject to your CPU power and the write speed of your backup device).  (2) Is it feasible simply to *compare* the live system to a “known good” backup?  (3) I’ve heard that [Tripwire](https://www.tripwire.com/products) is good, but I have no personal experience with it (and I am not affiliated).  Apparently it’s not free, but it offers a free trial.

Comment: Why run a script once a day instead of continuously running a background task capturing all file I/O operation like an anti-virus or FileMonitor does? This background task doesn't need to open the file, just to catch the write/create operation. The task write to a log file what it has catch and later, i.e. running once each day a script can create some sort of report or process changed files.